# How to compile all files that uses library in Nuitka?

Tags: python, compilation, nuitka

I've created program that uses lib rembg with included u2net.onnx(u2net.onnx in rembg library) to delete backgrounds. I can compile program without problems with PyInstaller, but with Nuitka there a lot of problems.
I am using this command:

```
nuitka --standalone --onefile --follow-imports --enable-plugin=tk-inter --include-plugin-directory="myenv\Lib\site-packages\rembg\u2net.onnx" --windows-icon-from-ico=icon.ico main.py
```

After running program and choosing files to remove backgrounds it gives me this error:
Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\roka\Desktop\pythob\PYTHON~1\MAIN~1.DIS\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
  File "C:\Users\roka\Desktop\pythob\PYTHON~1\MAIN~1.DIS\main.py", line 57, in remove_background
  File "C:\Users\roka\Desktop\pythob\PYTHON~1\MAIN~1.DIS\rembg\bg.py", line 132, in remove
  File "C:\Users\roka\Desktop\pythob\PYTHON~1\MAIN~1.DIS\rembg\session_factory.py", line 35, in new_session
  File "C:\Users\roka\Desktop\pythob\PYTHON~1\MAIN~1.DIS\onnxruntime\capi\onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 347, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\roka\Desktop\pythob\PYTHON~1\MAIN~1.DIS\onnxruntime\capi\onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 384, in _create_inference_session
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.NoSuchFile: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 3 : NO_SUCHFILE : Load model from C:\Users\roka\Desktop\pythob\PYTHON~1\MAIN~1.DIS\rembg\u2net.onnx failed:Load model C:\Users\roka\Desktop\pythob\PYTHON~1\MAIN~1.DIS\rembg\u2net.onnx failed. File doesn't exist
```

I've tried using --include-plugin-directory="myenv\Lib\site-packages\rembg\u2net.onnx" , --include-data-dir(gives error that I can't use that for some reason), using PyInstaller(worked well, but I need to use Nuitka), moving u2net.onnx to the file compilated directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve this problem myself, so rembg have some files that unnable to fully compile using nuitka or pyinstaller. To solve this I have downloaded rembg avg-lambda(it contains u2net.onnx that was needed to work)  and used --include-data-dir to go directly to rembg folder and just copy all of it.